# Flask Template Folder Not Found

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to deploy my flask app so that it is available on any computers in my LAN. However, when I execute it I get the following error in the apache2 error.log file :
[image]

The architecture of my app is the following:
[image]

This is for `__init__.py` (python3) :

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template,request
app = Flask('__name__')
@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])

def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template("index.html")
    else: 
        return render_template("index2.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And my code index.html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

For index2.html it is the same code as index.html only that the tag h1 has a different content.

When I executed this in locally (http://127.0.0.1:5000/) it was working fine.

I am following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFBRVJPhDGY

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: can you share your project structure ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 what do you mean? I put the structure of the file

Comment: are you using something like, `from cloud import app` ? if not then change `__init__.py` to `myapp.py` and in `app=flask(__name__, template_folder="../tmplates")`

Comment: Yes @sahasrara62 i am using from cloud import app in my .wsgi file

Comment: Just add template folder path in 'app=flask(template folder)'

Comment: Removed the quotes in `app = Flask('__name__')`. Flask needs this to be a package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
app = Flask('__name__')
```

do

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Flask uses the package/module name to locate the templates folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is working now. But I don't understand why by removing the quotes it works now because on another appliation I used the quotes and it was working fine

Comment: The quotes make `__name__` a literal string, instead of using it as variable that holds a package or module name. Flask wants the latter, and will resolve a path to the package/module and look for a templates directory there. Ymight not notice the problem until you need a template. Blueprints use the same mechanism, which is how each Blueprint can provide templates (and how Flask can find them).

If you're really curious, start at https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/app.py#L386 and follow how `import_name` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your deployment structure on the server. It's possible that your templates folder is in the wrong location. Like how you have it structured locally, the templates folder should be under your project root folder.